# Добавить в listbox текст из edit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

Как сделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку текст из поля появлялся последовательно в строки listbox-а?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `ListBox1.items.add('some text');` по-моему так

Comment: @Victor `...Add(Edit1.Text);` :)

Comment: @Igor Ну вам как мед так и ложкой)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вешаете обработчик события OnClick на кнопку. Должно получиться что-то типа такого:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Add(Edit1.Text);
end;
```